# Priority between a custom alignment guide and a Spacer in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Does anyone know if it is possible to set some kind of priority of a custom alignment guide?

I have a VStack where one of the items is an image(QR code) that is centered to "background view" outside the VStack with a custom alignment guide. (See picture)

[Image with QR code centered on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWT8O.png)

My problem is that I want this custom alignment guide to only apply if the all items in the VStack fits in the screen. The Spacer does not seams to have any effect when I center the image with the custom alignment guide. I have tried to set layout priority but with no success.

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
    
    private enum CenterAztecImage: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return context[VerticalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
    
    static let centerAztecImage = VerticalAlignment(CenterAztecImage.self)
}

struct InactiveTicketSwiftUIView<ViewModel>: View where ViewModel: InactiveTicket {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
       ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .centerAztecImage)) {
           
           viewModel.backgroundColor
               .ignoresSafeArea()
              .alignmentGuide(.centerAztecImage) { d in
                  d[VerticalAlignment.centerAztecImage]
              }
            
           VStack {
               
               VStack {
                   
                   viewModel.priceCategoryColor.frame(height: 16.0)
                   
                   HStack {
                       Text(viewModel.priceCategory).padding()
                       Spacer()
                       viewModel.operatorImage.padding()
                   }
                   
                   Divider()
                   
                   // Here is the image that is centered with a custom alignment guide
                   viewModel.fakeAztecImage
                       .resizable()
                       .frame(width: 224, height: 224, alignment: .leading)
                       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                       .padding()
                       .alignmentGuide(.centerAztecImage, computeValue: { d in
                           return d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                       })
                   
                   Divider()
                   
                   // Multiple Text views for testing
                   Text(viewModel.type).padding()
                   Text(viewModel.type).padding()
                   Text(viewModel.type).padding()
                   Text(viewModel.type).padding()
                   Text(viewModel.type).padding()
               }
               .frame(width: 320.0, alignment: .center)
               .background(.white)
               .cornerRadius(12)
               .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 4)
               
               // This Spacer seams to be allways be "overriden" by the custom alignment guide that centers the image
               Spacer(minLength: 20).layoutPriority(1)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, your issue is that the stuff below your "Aztec Image" is getting pushed off the screen when you are explicitly forcing the centre coordinate of this image to align itself with the centre of the screen. 

You could use a GeometryReader to compare the height of the space from the bottom edge of the AztecImage to the bottom of the screen, to the height of the views underneath the AztecImage and then use a conditional to apply the alignment guide, but this will take a lot of effort. Why not just use a ScrollView for the stuff underneath the AztecImage?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes a scroll view would work. However, in some cases there is an "activate ticket" button under the aztec image, and we want that button to be visible all the time regardless of screen size. With storyboard I manage to do this with constraints with different priority, and I was hoping to be able to do the same thing with SwiftUI in a rather simple way.